# How to horizontally center a modal div even after the browser is resized?

Tags: jquery, css

I m trying to add an item to the DOM using jquery. I want it to overlay on top(z-index) of all other content (there are hundreds of z-indices set already) and it should be center aligned at all times.

While adding this div to the DOM, i m setting its 'left' property to $(window).width()/2 - 971/2. 971 is the width of the div I m trying to add. This is the CSS for it

```
width: 971px;
height: 669px;
background-image: url(/path/to/image/);
position: absolute;
margin: 0px auto;
z-index: 2500;
```

The problem is, the div does not stay centered after the browser is resized.  I ve even tried with left: 50% and some negative left margin in pixels. If I set the 'left' property in relation with the 'screen' then it s centered only if the browser window is maximized by the user.

What is a good way to position this absolutely positioned div with a high z-index such that its always centered?

Comment: Why are you even specifing a left value for it? By having `margin: auto` it should automatically be centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#someId{
    width: 971px;
    height: 669px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;

    margin-left:-486px; /* 971/2 */
    margin-top:-335px; /* 669/2 */

    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

    background-image: url(/path/to/image/);
    z-index: 2500;
}
```

I know you've said you tried this - but this has always worked for me in any browser running in standards compliant mode (even ie) it might have been thrown off by not taking border or padding into consideration. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/U3RrT/

I've just realised that it may be because you have set an element above it with a different `position` property; try `position:fixed;`.

Comment: I had set the position to fixed but then the problem arises when you resize the browser.

Comment: this should automatically update in all browsers - does the jsfiddle example work for you when resized?

Answer (score 2):

First, `margin: 0px auto;` is enough to horizontally centre a div. So, just removing the `left` property may be able to fix the issue.

---

**IF not**, since you are using jQuery, there is a `.resize()` event of `window`which you can control to fix the appearance again.

For example

```
function resizeMyBox() {
  //code to resize
}       
$(function() {
   resizeMyBox();  // Resize on DOM ready
});
$(window).resize(function() {
   resizeMyBox(); //Resize again on every resize
});
```

Comment: The position is set to absolute, hence I have to specify the 'left' property. I wish I could do this without adding an event listener just for this :(

Comment: @saganbyte, You have already included the jquery in your code, so there is no harm on using it.